# Маршрутизация древовидного каталога в asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, чпу

Есть каталог древовидный, в нем пути (url'ы) сделаны так **Home/PageList/d9270a18-2469-4cdc-b6a8-2395dc80fbaf**,
где d9270a18-2469-4cdc-b6a8-2395dc80fbaf уникальный id (Guid).

На какой бы элемент мы не переходили по иерархии он все равно выглядит таким образом.

Как сделать маршрутизацию (сделать url'ы каталога ЧПУ) этого каталога(см. фото), чтобы выглядело так

**/Витрина/бу-оборудование/холодильная-горка-pastorfrigor**

и т.п., т.е чтобы url брался из названия[image: каталог]

Answer (score 1):

кроме роутинга надо бы еще и формировать урл правильно.
разварачивайте дерево в строчку /нода1/нода2/нода3/..../нодаN и уже получившееся значение пихайте в дефолтовую переменную, которая у вас прописана в роутах, по умолчанию это id или если взять ответ Павла за основу то path, в Html.Action должно быть примерно так: Html.Action("action", "controller", new {path="нода1/нода2/нода3/..../нодаN"})

контроллером разгрибайте параметр path как Вам удобно

P.S.
кстати, неплохо было бы добавить отдельное поле для URL каждой ноды, и я бы их еще в транслитерацию загонял. При встречающихся одинаковых нодах добовлял бы индекс в конце например Holodilnik и Holodilnik-1 и тд.
когда все это хозяйство прилетает в контроллер, то разбираем уже не по guid а по полю в котором у нас url ноды в нужном виде

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто добавить маршрут, принимающий любой путь, в конец списка маршрутов:

```
routes.MapRoute("Main", "{*path}", new { controller = "Main", action = "Show" });
```

Теперь любой запрос, не попадающий под другие маршруты и обработчики, будет попадать в контроллер `Main`, действие `Show`. Сам путь будет передаваться в параметр `path`.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, не помогло.

Comment: @DavidD Что означает "не помогло"? Какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: Ничего не происходит. урлы какие были так и остались.
ошибки нет

Comment: @DavidD, что означает "урлы остались"? Вы что, ожидали, что кто-то магически изменит все отдаваемые урлы с учетом структуры вашей БД? Ничего подобного. Это вообще-то ваша задача - формировать корректные урлы и разбирать принятые параметры. Маршрутизация тут только иногда немного помогает.